# Dragging View object off screen and replacing it with an other

Tags: android, object, view, gesture, drag

I have an `ImageButton` and have implemented the interface for listening to touch events and detecting gestures. I want to know which specific method i must implement in order to drag my `ImageButton` offscreen (making it invisible i guess) and then replace it with a second different one. I think it should be `onFling()` or `onScroll()` , but i dont how exactly to code it. Here is the code and image :

```
public class fourthActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageButton ib;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fourth_activity);

        // listen to touch events
        ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib3);
        ib.setOnClickListener(this);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this,new MyGestureDetector());
        gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View view,MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        };
        ib.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(fourthActivity.this,"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    class MyGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onDown (MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```